# bootstrap navbar toggler hamburger button is not responding to clicks

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark bg-dark navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class "nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class "nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class "nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

When I shrink the chrome window, the hamburger button is showed up, but when i click on it, nothing happens.
I`m using the latest version of bootstarp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `bootstrap.min.js` file. Make sure that have a connection in your file

Comment: what is "bootstrap.min.js"? I linked bootstrap to html.index via 
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: or this one `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: ok it works, thanks! what`s wrong with my link? I copied from the official Bootstrap site

Comment: sometimes i have faced the same problem, if you got solved, then please mark this solved and do upvote. thank you

Comment: Lol. Do you know to explain it?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448444/bootstrap-toggle-button-is-not-working] (please read this)